# Proof any arithmetic progression coprime count same as toting function of n

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Euler's totient function of n gives us the number of integers coprime to n that are less than or equal to n and greater than or equal to 1. Clearly the arithmetic progression {d, 2d, ..., nd} with common difference d and length n has a count of integers coprime to n equal to the totient function of n if d is already coprime to n. However I am having trouble proving that any arithmetic progression is also equal to totient function of n. That is, why is the count of integers coprime to n for {a+d, a+2d, ..., a+nd} the same as the totient function of n, where a can be any integer and d is coprime to n? I tried both simple and strong induction but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle this problem, we will use three facts.

1) Look at {$d, 2d, \cdots, nd$} (mod $n$).  Then since $n$ is coprime to $d$, this will be simply a permutation of {$1, 2, \cdots, n$} [e.g., we can go from the first to the second by multiplying by $d^{-1}$ (mod $n$)].

2) {$a+1, a+2, \cdots, a+n$} is also a permutation of {$1, 2, \cdots, n$} (mod $n$). [e.g., we can go from the first to the second by adding $-a$ (mod $n$)].

3) Given $k\in\Bbb Z$, $a + kn$ is coprime to $n$ if and only if $a$ is.

Proof: Suppose $a$ is NOT coprime to $n$.  Then there exists $c=$GCD($a, n$)$>1$ so that $a = cd$ and $n=ce$ for some $d, e\in\Bbb N$.  Then $a+kn=cd+kce = c(d+ke)$, and $n=ce$; so $c>1$ divides the GCD($a+kn,n$), and so $a+kn$ is NOT coprime to $n$.

Conversely, if $a+kn$ is NOT coprime to $n$ then let $a'=a+kn$.  By the argument above, $a'+(-k)n=a$ is NOT coprime to $n$ as well.  Therefore, $a$ is coprime to $n$ iff $a+kn$ is coprime to $n$.

This implies that we can reduce a set (mod $n$) without affecting the number of integers that are coprime to $n$.
So, let us count the number of integers in {$a+d, a+2d, \cdots, a+nd$} coprime to $n$.

- Since given $k\in\Bbb Z$, $a+kn$ is coprime to $n$ if and only if $a$ is coprime to $n$, then this number will equal the number of integers in {$a+d, a+2d, \cdots, a+nd$} (reduced mod $n$) coprime to $n$.
- Since {$a+d, a+2d, \cdots, a+nd$} is a permutation of {$d, 2d, \cdots, nd$} (mod $n$), then this number will equal the number of integers in {$a+d, a+2d, \cdots, a+nd$} (reduced mod $n$) coprime to $n$.
- Since {$d, 2d, \cdots, nd$} is a permutation of {$1, 2, \cdots n$} (mod $n$), then this number is equal to the number of integers in {$1, 2, \cdots, n$} coprime to $n$.
- Therefore, by definition of $\phi(n)$, the number we are looking for equals $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I updated my answer to reflect that.  Let me know if this is still not enough.

Comment: I still do not understand. Could you explain the last paragraph a bit better?

Comment: OK, I split it into 4 steps.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: How do we know that a set over a mod will behave the same as a set without?

Comment: By the comment that a+kn is coprime to n if and only if a is coprime to n.  This is because:
a is NOT coprime to n iff there exists b>1 so b|a and b|n.  Then b|a+kn as well; so a+kn is not coprime to n as well.  The converse is true by taking k=-k.

Comment: Still don't get why a+kn provides a count for the number of integers coprime to n

Comment: Sorry, I hit my daily rep cap today. I'll update my answer in an hour to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks bro I love u I will accept as soon as I can understand what's going on

Comment: OK, I updated the answer.  Sorry it's later than I anticipated.

Comment: Ok, u said a+kn mod n gives the number of coprime, aka a gives the number of coprimes. But consider n=3 and d=2 and a=1. There are 2 numbers in the set coprime to 3 when there should be 1

Comment: Why should there be 1?  The numbers coprime to 3 in the set {1, 2, 3} are 1 and 2; so there are two of them: so getting 2 such numbers in the set is correct.

Comment: A+kn mod n = 1 when a = 1. U said a+kn gives number of coprimes. Or am I missing something

Comment: No, it's the number of coprimes in the set {a+kn} as $a$ ranges from 1 to $n$, that equals the total number of coprimes.  I think what you are missing is, the way this proof works is by showing the the *number* of coprimes does not change as we reduce modulo n, or as we add a number, or as we multiply by a number.  So if $\phi(n)$ was the initial number of coprimes, it remains $\phi(n)$ as we do all the operations on it.

Comment: Ok, so what is a in {a+d, a+2d, ..., a+Nd}?